# Why do composers use fermatas?

Tags: theory, notation, composition, ties, fermata

I am taking part in a music theory course on Coursera, and I could not understand the difference between a tie and a fermata. Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fermata, or pause, lasts an undetermined length of time. Not too long, but at the player's discretion. It can make , say, a semibreve in 4/4 last 5 beats. Ties join the same pitch notes for a couple of reasons. Over a bar line, so the second note doesn't get played again, but carries on; to make up a note length that's not available; and to write notes in a readable manner, such as the second and third beats in 4/4 played as one note. A fermata can also be used over a rest, again, to make it slightly longer than written.

Comment: Actually, fermatas should be held approximately twice the duration of the original note value. The exact length is, as you alluded to, determined by the musicians and the stylistic context of the music.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - Hmm. *Twice as long* sounds a bit dogmatic.

Comment: @aparente001 - depends how much rubato one applies...

Comment: @Tim - I agree.  If jjmusicnotes had put this contribution in an Answer, I would have voted it down.

Comment: Ah, but would you, as so few do, explained why it was voted down?

Comment: @aparente001 - both of you gentleman apparently did not read the *second half* of my comment in which I explicitly state that the exact length is determined by the musicians / conductor and the stylistic context of the music, among other things (such as the performance space). Fermatas being held *approximately* twice the value of the original note is a fairly common performance practice, though is it by no means strict. Since fermatas themselves are non-explicit, relative durations of holds should be clearly indicated in the score with alternative symbols, text, or time written.

Comment: @aparente001 - My explanation of relative fermata duration is supported both by Elaine Gould and Kurt Stone, both of whom have written extensively on contemporary music notation. Additionally by David Blumberg, an author of musical semiotics.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - It sounds like you've got some good material here to write an Answer.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - if a composer wanted a note/chord held for a specific length, a 'proper' dot would be used, I guess. If he wanted it left up to discretion, a fermata would suffice.

Comment: There definitely  is some artistic license in regards to fermatas.

Comment: @Tim - perhaps, if the composer was indeed using notation where a dot would be helpful, but that's not always the case. With proportional notation, they would simply draw a line, for example. If a composer wants a fermata held for, let's say 11" (irrespective of tempo), they'll need to specify by writing the time in above the fermata and changing the symbol to show appropriate relative duration to other fermatas in the piece. As always with music, there are several ways to notate a specific sound or gesture.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - That's interesting. I now have this mental image of the conductor with a stopwatch counting 11 secs!!  Bizarre springs to mind!

Comment: @Tim - Not as bizarre as you might think...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zY7UK-6aaNA

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - I'd nearly forgotten about that. But I bet it wasn't written as a fermata...   Sometimes I used to say to my ex-wife: John Cage...

Comment: @Tim - You're right, it's not written with fermatas, but the conductor does use a stopwatch to time each of the three movements, which are exact durations.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes the score I have seen for 4'33" says `I TACET II TACET III TACET` and specifies that the work may last for any amount of time.  This score was prepared after the first performance, however, because it notes the details of that performance, including the duration of each movement.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like a strange music theory course since a tie and a fermata are absurdly different things.

A tie means that a note has to be written as several consecutive notes for notational reasons (interfering bar lines or line breaks, hard to read rhythm, unrepresentable total note duration) but is a single note with the total length of all tied written notes.

A fermata means that a note serves as a temporary (or actual) ending and should be held for longer than its nominal value: the music is coming to a stop here.  Usually fermata are on notes ending at the same time in all instruments but there are cases where a new start threads into a fermata, naturally in a voice that cannot itself end in a fermata.

There also is the "laissez-vibrer tie": those are ties ending in the void.  They indicate for percussive instruments like guitar to not dampen (or unfinger) the strings in question after the preceding note has ended but just let them ring out naturally while continuing without pause otherwise.

But while a fermata means "end this note late, stopping the clock", "laissez-vibrer" means to not give any determinable ending and keeping the speed.

Comment: Actually, a tie does not mean that several consecutive notes need to be written.  **A tie simply joins two or more notes together.**  Music should technically not stop at fermatas, since all they indicate is a hold.  A *caesura* indicates a break in the music. For those who don't speak French, "laissez-vibrer" means "let vibrate" and is typically notated as "l.v." in scores where they occur.